# Wampserver do not start

Tags: wamp

On starting WAMP I'm getting this error:

> the procedure entry point `_crtCreateSymbolicLinkW` could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library
>   `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP110.dll`

Comment: Did you install WAMPServer or install Apache manually?

Comment: Did you install all the required MSVC runtime libraries? See [The WAMPServer backup repo and download the installer for all the required runtimes](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) its at the bottom of the linked to page

Comment: yes i install all required MSVC .dll

Comment: The message says maybe you did not install all the right versions of the MSVC Runtime DLL's

Comment: Did you install these runtimes, or did you copy the dll files into `\windows\system32\`? You have to install them a copy will not work properly